# Is there a way to to re-import photos from an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, photos

I imported photos from an iPhone with rotate option turned on. Then I saw I should have turned rotate option off, so I deleted the folder with the imported photos from my PC.

Now I’m not able to re-import because no photos are recognized as new. I tried Photos (Photo Gallery app), and even though it picks up my iphone device, it doesn't pull any photos. How can I reset and/or rename the setting so I can re-import the photos that I deleted from my PC?

Answer (score 1):

Once you deleted file it does not delete permanently. In first step it goes into trash(mac os) / recycle bin ( windows). You can put back your deleted file from here. Even if you delete files from trash/ recycle bin you can retrieve files by third party software (once I have done it). Because, deleted files from trash/recycle bin are stored into a internal storage/memory of the operating system(OS) running on that Computer.

Answer (score 1):

Delete this file:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Photo Acquisition\PreviouslyAcquired.db
```

That’s it. Your PC will now re-import everything.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 7, see this article. It should be applicable to other versions of Windows as well (the location of *AppData* may be different though).
http://www.natashajudd.com/re-importing-photos-in-windows-7/

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. This is a good suggestion, however it does not make a good answer. Please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) and possibly edit your post.

Comment: The link in your answer seems to have gone dead.  Here is a link to an archived copy: https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20141221212249/http://www.natashajudd.com:80/re-importing-photos-in-windows-7/  Alas, the styling makes the text hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by deleting one photo from Photos app which was still on iPhone. Suddenly all already imported photos were shown as available for import. Not sure if this is reproducible.